# Clean design and implementation for data import library

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have been given the task of developing a small library (using C# 3.0 and .NET 3.5) to provide data import functionality for an application.

The spec is:

- Data can be imported from CSV file
  (potentially other file formats in the
  future)
- The CSV files can contain any
  schema and number of rows, with a
  maximum file size of 10MB.
- It must be
  possible to change the datatype and
  column name of each column in the CSV
  file.
- It must be possible to exclude
  columns in the CSV file from the
  import.
- Importing the data will
  result in a table matching the schema
  being created in a SQL Server database, and then
  being populated using rows in the
  CSV.

I've been playing around with ideas for a while now my current code feels like it has been hacked together a bit.

My current implementation approach is:

1. Open CSV and estimate the schema,
   store in an ImportSchema class
2. Allow the schema to be modified.
3. Use SMO to create the table in SQL
   according to the schema.
4. Create a System.Data.DataTable instance using the schema
   for datatypes.
5. Use [CsvReader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx) to read the CSV
   data into the DataTable.
6. Apply column name changes and remove unwanted columns from DataTable.
7. Use System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy() to add the rows from the DataTable into the created database table.

This sounds overly complex to me and I am facing a mental block trying to wrap it up neatly in a handful of testable/extensible objects.

Any suggestions/thoughts on ways to approach this problem, both from an implementation and a design perspective?

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Do you have to use CSV? It is usually much better to integrate with XML and use XML Schemas- you then don't have to guess the types as they defined in the schema.

Comment: Yep, that part of the spec is set in stone.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in some previous SO answers, take a look at the [FileHelpers Libraray](http://www.filehelpers.com/). This might be at least helpful in your task to import and analyze the CSV files.

Comment: FileHelpers library is good but from what I can tell you need to to know the format of the data so it can be mapped to an existing object..